# How to configure RabbitMQ ssl port to only listen to specific VPC interface

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I have a VPC that is setup on AWS. Let's say inside this VPC I have two EC2 machines running, Machine A and Machine B. RabbitMQ live in A and I have some clients living in B. Machine B has a private IP 1.2.3.4 and I want it to talk to RabbitMQ via TLS. I tried using this in my config

`{ssl_listeners, [{'1.2.3.4', 5671}]}`

However the client cannot connect, but this

`{ssl_listeners, [5671]}` works.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

What you would probably like to do is to make RabbitMQ to listen on MachineA interface to given VPC. Hence, you need not to configure it to listen on IP of MachineB but MachineA instead.

Let's assume that MachineA, this with RabbitMQ on it has IP `1.2.3.99`:

`{ssl_listeners, [{'1.2.3.99', 5671}]}`

By not giving any particular address to listen on it listens on 0.0.0.0 (so any) by default. That's why below just works:

`{ssl_listeners, [5671]}`

Comment: but what if I only want Machine B, and noone else, to talk with RabbitMQ on 5671?

Comment: Then you will need to configure some kind of firewall and let only packets that has source equals that IP. 

In AWS case you can define Security Group that only allows Inbound traffic on port 5671 with source as assumed `1.2.3.99`. Then add MachineA to newly defined group.

Be careful while dealing with security groups. It's possible to limit e.g. SSH access to the instance accidentally.